# rails bringing back all checkboxes instead of only selected one

Tags: ruby-on-rails, checkbox, simple-form

I am using `simple_form` and have a following sample tag:

```
<%= f.input :medical_conditions, :label=>false, :collection => medical_conditons, :as => :check_boxes%>
```

The collection holds about 100 checkboxes.  However, when user only selects 1 or 2, everything is still getting saved to the database like this:

```
---
- ""
- ""
- ""
```

`medical_conditions` is a simple array in my `application_helper`

```
def medical_conditons
t = [
    "Allergies/Hay Fever",
    "Diabetes",
    "Heart Surgery"]
return t
end
```

the `medical_conditions` field is a `:string` field.

What do I need to do so that only values that are selected are saved in comma separated manner.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not simple_form behavior. It is from Rails. See this: http://d.pr/6O2S

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this in your controller (guessing at how you wrote your create/update methods)...

```
params[:medical_conditions].delete('') #this will remove the empty strings
@instance.update_attribute(:medical_conditions, params[:medical_conditions].join(','))
#or however you want to save the input, but the key is the .join(',') which will
#create a comma-separated string of only the selected values, which is exactly
#what you're looking for me thinks :-)
```

If that does the trick for you, I'd consider making a private helper method that formats the params for you so that you can use it in #create, #update, or wherever else you need it.  This should keep things a little cleaner and more "rails way-ish" in your crud actions.